weird arrangement of geom_col when logged
I have the following datatframe:
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

meta<- structure(list(valid_name = c("Katsuwonus pelamis", "Thunnus albacares", 
"Thunnus obesus", "Xiphias gladius", "Istiophorus platypterus", 
"Euthynnus affinis", "Coryphaena hippurus", "Acanthocybium solandri", 
"Prionace glauca", "Istiompax indica", "Thunnus alalunga", "Elagatis bipinnulata", 
"Aphareus rutilans", "Isurus oxyrinchus", "Lethrinus microdon", 
"Epinephelus chlorostigma", "Variola louti", "Kajikia audax", 
"Lutjanus argentimaculatus", "Thunnus tonggol", "Lethrinus nebulosus", 
"Lethrinus mahsena", "Scarus ghobban", "Carcharhinus falciformis", 
"Ruvettus pretiosus", "Hexanchus griseus", "Carcharhinus longimanus", 
"Scomberomorus commerson", "Alopias vulpinus", "Sphyrna zygaena", 
"Carcharhinus amblyrhynchos", "Tetrapturus angustirostris", "Auxis thazard", 
"Thunnus maccoyii", "Carcharhinus limbatus", "Lepidocybium flavobrunneum"
), catch_sum_t = c(67611.399067582, 41231.338976487, 7521.951274017, 
3372.17835057, 3125.992929547, 2774.303351886, 2469.5067046969, 
1929.1503508411, 1415.044600755, 890.4079532428, 491.102370364, 
382, 304, 218.977768838, 176, 130, 89, 88.159658003, 73, 59.134772927, 
58, 54, 46, 9.635956749, 0.2936755491, 0.2561460114, 0.1091181203, 
0.06608934, 0.0466742506, 0.0038898787, 0.002847962, 0.0028091134, 
0.002452496, 0.001190259, 0.000695997, 0.0004155168), DemersPelag = c("pelagic-oceanic", 
"pelagic-oceanic", "pelagic-oceanic", "pelagic-oceanic", "pelagic-oceanic", 
"pelagic-neritic", "pelagic-neritic", "pelagic-oceanic", "pelagic-oceanic", 
"pelagic-oceanic", "pelagic-oceanic", "reef-associated", "reef-associated", 
"pelagic-oceanic", "reef-associated", "reef-associated", "reef-associated", 
"pelagic-oceanic", "reef-associated", "pelagic-neritic", "reef-associated", 
"reef-associated", "reef-associated", "reef-associated", "benthopelagic", 
"bathydemersal", "pelagic-oceanic", "pelagic-neritic", "pelagic-oceanic", 
"pelagic-oceanic", "reef-associated", "pelagic-oceanic", "pelagic-neritic", 
"pelagic-oceanic", "reef-associated", "benthopelagic")), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data. Frame"))

I want to plot it:
ggplot(meta) +
  geom_col(aes(reorder(valid_name, catch_sum_t, "sum"),catch_sum_t, fill=DemersPelag))+
  scale_y_log10(labels = scales::label_comma())+
  coord_flip()

I dont understand why bars look like that and centered at some weird number and not zero:

i would like to see emth like this:


What do you mean by: "why bars look like that"?

@Edward: the starting point of bars is unclear to me. I assumed it should start at 1.

You can use a pseudo log axis to keep the left-most value at zero (or pseudo zero). Also, small values may not appear on a log-transmformed barchart, so I would recommend a dotplot for this data instead.
breaks <- unique(c(0,
                   seq(1e0, 1e1, 1e0), 
                   seq(1e1, 1e2, 1e1),
                   seq(1e2, 1e3, 1e2),
                   seq(1e3, 1e4, 1e3),
                   seq(1e4, 1e5, 1e4)))

labs = c(0, 1, 
         rep("",8), "10", 
         rep("",8), "100",
         rep("",8), "1,000",
         rep("",8), "10,000",
         rep("",8), "100,000")

ggplot(meta, aes(x=reorder(valid_name, catch_sum_t, "sum"), 
                       y=catch_sum_t, 
                       col=DemersPelag)) +
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_segment(aes(yend=0, xend=reorder(valid_name, catch_sum_t, "sum"))) + 
  coord_flip()  +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = pseudo_log_trans(base = 10),
                     breaks = breaks,
                     labels = labs) +
  labs(x="Name")



Do you want this?  I think the output is not as expected because you took transformed axis function without actually transforming the axis/variable
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(meta) +
  geom_col(aes(reorder(valid_name, catch_sum_t, "sum"), log10(catch_sum_t), fill =
                 DemersPelag)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma()) +
  coord_flip()


Created on 2024-04-08 with reprex v2.1.0

I want the actual values labeled  on the x axis, not the logged ones
